# How to pass variable from controller to all view files (.ctp) in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller

My controller : `Controller/appController/OrdersController.php`

I have a function named `nocontact()` and I can pass variable to nocontact.ctp as follows:

```
 $allNoContacts = $result;
        $service_charge=$this->ServiceCharge->find('all');

        $zero_service_charge=$this->ZeroServiceCharge->find('all');
        $zero_service_charge=$zero_service_charge[0]['ZeroServiceCharge']['items'];
        $this->set(compact('allNoContacts','service_charge','zero_service_charge'));
```

How can I pass this variable to all view files under OrdersController?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the variable in beforeRender method of your OrdersController.

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $this->set('name', 'value');
}
```